# How to change text dynamically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text

I am trying to create a simple counter which will have 2 buttons one to increase count and other to decrease it and a number displayed in between them.

I am using this code.

```
import 'package:expensewhat/main.dart';
import 'authorization3.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'custom_paint.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/percent_indicator.dart';

class NewTrip extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewTripState createState() => _NewTripState();
}

class _NewTripState extends State<NewTrip> {

  int current = 2;



  void decCurrent() {
    if(current>2){
      setState(() {     

        current = current - 1;
        print(current);

    });
    }

  }

  void incCurrent() {
    if(current<10){
      setState(() {    

        current = current + 1;       

        print(current);     

    });
    }

  } 


  @override 



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: CustomPaint(
            painter: Backcircles(),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Expense',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 25.0),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'What',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 60.0,
                ),

                //User INFO

                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 30.0,
                  ),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ListView(
                    primary: false,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0,
                      right: 15.0,
                      top: 20.0,
                    ),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 30.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //greeting text
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'New Trip',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 30.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),

                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            ),

                            //select number of members

                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Select number of trip members'),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),


                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [



                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                ),

                                Row(  
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Center(
                                      child: CircularPercentIndicator(  
                                        radius: 130,
                                        animation: true,
                                        animationDuration: 1200,
                                        lineWidth: 2,
                                        percent: current/10,
                                        center: Text(  
                                          current.toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(  
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 20,                                          
                                          ),

                                        ),
                                        circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.butt,
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                                        progressColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),


                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    RaisedButton(
                                      onPressed: decCurrent,
                                      child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '$current',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    RaisedButton(
                                      onPressed: incCurrent,
                                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),

                                SizedBox(height: 20,),

                                 Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                      height: 40,                                      
                                      child: FlatButton( 
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,),
                                      ),

                                      color: Color(0xFF03328A),
                                      child: new Text('Continue',
                                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                          if(current == 2){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth2()),);
                                          } 
                                          else if(current == 3){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth3()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 4){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth4()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 5){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth5()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 6){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth6()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 7){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth7()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 8){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth8()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 9){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth9()),);
                                          }
                                          else if(current == 10){
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Auth10()),);
                                          }



                                      },
                                    ),
                              ),
                              ),
                              ]
                              ),

                              SizedBox(height: 20,),

                              Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                      height: 40,                                      
                                      child: FlatButton( 
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,),
                                      ),

                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      child: new Text('Back',
                                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black)),
                                      onPressed: () {                                          
                                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page0()),);
                                          },  

                                           ),
                              ),
                              ),
                              ]
                              ),

                              ],
                            )


                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The value of current is changing in console as I tap buttons, but it is not getting updated in the text widget. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is the code snippet just one big file or is it separated into two files? Where is current defined relative to the scaffold snippet you have shown us? I would also refactor your setState logic. Meaning, move your if condition outside of setState and only update if your if condition is true.

Comment: I have updated with the full page code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this code is working:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(NewTrip());
}

class NewTrip extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewTripState createState() => _NewTripState();
}

class _NewTripState extends State<NewTrip> {

  int current = 2;

   void decCurrent() {
    setState(() {
      if (current > 2) {

        current = current - 1;
        print(current);
      }
    });
  }

  void incCurrent() {
    setState(() {
      if (current < 10) {

        current = current + 1;       

        print(current);
      }

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
   children: [
        RaisedButton(
           onPressed: decCurrent,
           child: Icon(Icons.remove),
       ),
       SizedBox(
           width: 10,
       ),
       Text(
         '$current',
       ),
       SizedBox(
       width: 10,
       ),
       RaisedButton(
          onPressed: incCurrent,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
     ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You modified code is working here as well:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: NewTrip()));
}

class NewTrip extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewTripState createState() => _NewTripState();
}

class _NewTripState extends State<NewTrip> {

  int current = 2;



  void decCurrent() {
    if(current>2){
      setState(() {     

        current = current - 1;
        print(current);

    });
    }

  }

  void incCurrent() {
    if(current<10){
      setState(() {    

        current = current + 1;       

        print(current);     

    });
    }

  } 


  @override 



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 25.0,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Expense',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 25.0),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'What',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: 60.0,
                ),

                //User INFO

                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 30.0,
                  ),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(75.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: ListView(
                    primary: false,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0,
                      right: 15.0,
                      top: 20.0,
                    ),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 30.0,
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //greeting text
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'New Trip',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 30.0,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),

                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20.0,
                            ),

                            //select number of members

                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Select number of trip members'),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),


                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [



                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                ),

                                Row(  
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(  
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),


                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    RaisedButton(
                                      onPressed: decCurrent,
                                      child: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '$current',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    RaisedButton(
                                      onPressed: incCurrent,
                                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),

                                SizedBox(height: 20,),

                                 Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                      height: 40,                                      
                                      child: FlatButton( 
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,),
                                      ),

                                      color: Color(0xFF03328A),
                                      child: new Text('Continue',
                                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
                                      onPressed: () {}

                                    ),
                              ),
                              ),
                              ]
                              ),

                              SizedBox(height: 20,),

                              Row(children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Container(
                                      height: 40,                                      
                                      child: FlatButton( 
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black,),
                                      ),

                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      child: new Text('Back',
                                          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black)),
                                      onPressed: () { }

                                           ),
                              ),
                              ),
                              ]
                              ),

                              ],
                            )


                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is working with a normal scaffold..but in my project I am using Listview as well. Does that induce the issue? I have updated with the full page code by the way.

Comment: Hello @Shahbaz your code is working here; I added a working example where I left only 1 import (material.dart); start with this and then add other pieces to find what is not working.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I found out that the code is working fine until I use my custom paint. For some reason text is not updating if I am using custom paint. Thanks anyways.